# Best Approach for GIT log graph with separate and individual line for every branch

Tags: git, branch, git-flow

I wanna to use `git-flow` as workflow in git. But I have problem with see `git log --graph`. For example I have four branch:

```
 -master-    -develop-    -feature/sms-    -release/v1.0
    |            |             |                 |
```

I want to see every branch in separate and individual like blow image:
[image: git graph]

What should I do? or Which tool is good for my need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You literally cannot do this in general.  You can fake it up for specific cases, which might be good enough for you; but you will have to do this yourself, because Git will not.

The reason for this is simple: the graph you show is a lie.  It tries to pretend that Git works forwards.  Git does not: **Git works backwards.**

In Git, commits are not, in general, *on a single branch*.  Instead, commits are on *many branches simultaneously*.  Here is a textual representation of that same graph:

```
master:    A--B-----------------------P--...
               \                     /
release:        \                K--M
                 \              /    \
develop:          C-----F------I------R--...
                   \     \    /
feature1:           D--E-----H
                           \
feature2:                   G--J--L--N--...
```

This, too, is a lie: it implies that commit `A`, for instance, is *only* on `master`.  In fact, commit `A` is on *every* branch.

Since there are `...` parts that we cannot see, it is hard to say for certain whether commits `G-J-L-N-...` are on more than one branch: we need to start at the end, like Git does, to see reality instead of a lie.  We can say, though, that these commits are definitely on `feature2` right now.  Meanwhile, commits `C` and `F` are on *both* `feature2` *and* `develop`.  The only branch we cannot be sure contains the `D-E-H` sequence is `feature2`: all four of those commits are *definitely* on `feature1`, but also *definitely* on `develop`, because `I` is on `develop` and `I` reaches back to `H`.  Meanwhile commit `K` is on `release`, but since `K` reaches back to `I`, `I` is *also* on `release`; since `I` tracks back to both `F` and `H`, those two commits are also on `release`.

In short, the problem here is that we are attempting to work *forwards*.  Git does not work forwards.  **Git works backwards**, starting from the *last* commit on a branch.  Let's assume that we do in fact have these last commits, and re-draw everything:

```
A--B-----------------------P   <-- master
    \                     /
     \                K--M
      \              /    \
       C-----F------I------R   <-- develop
        \     \    /
         D--E-----H
                \
                 G--J--L--N   <-- feature2
```

This drawing is truthful, rather than a lie (well, presumably, for some repository at some time).

The three names I added here are the only names that we *need* to retain all the commits shown, because they are the only three *last commits*.  We can add another name, such as `feature1`, pointing to, say, commit `H`, and more names as we like:

```
A--B-----------------------P   <-- master
    \                     /
     \                K--M   <-- release
      \              /    \
       C-----F------I------R   <-- develop
        \     \    /
         D--E-----H   <-- feature1
                \
                 G--J--L--N   <-- feature2
```

This last graph is a (not necessarily *the*, but *a*) truthful way to draw things.  The name `release` identifies commit `M`, and from `M`, we—and Git—can work backwards to find commit `K`, then continue back from `K` to `I`, and on to both `F` and `H` simultaneously.  Then from `F` and `H` we can work back to `C` and `E` simultaneously, and to `D` (which also goes back to `C`); and from `C` we can walk back to `B` and then to `A`.  So commits `A-B-C-D-E-F-H-I-K-M` are *all reachable from `release`*.

**If we delete the name `release`, nothing happens to the commits.**  The commits are all still there.  They just are no longer contained in the `release` branch, which no longer exists.  They are still contained in `master`, because `master` starts at—ends at?—`P`, which works backwards to both `M` and `B`.  Since `P` reaches `M`, every commit reachable *from* `M` is also reachable from `P`.

If you think of this as driving down a one-way street, in a network of one-way streets, you're on the path to enlightenment.  For (much) more about this, I recommend working through the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  Pay close attention to the idea that what you want is to have your tools *hide (some) commits from you* (on the [Making Sense of the Display](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graphs-and-git/making-sense-of-the-display.html) page).

Note that there are other version control systems that work the way you would like Git to work.  Mercurial, in particular, is very similar to Git, except that commits are *on the branch they are made on, forever*.  Each commit is only on *one* branch.  The commit that contains a branch remains the same, regardless of what you do with your branch names.  In Git, because the *names* move while the commits remain unchanged, the *set of branches that contains any given commit* changes all the time!  If you are not prepared to have this happen to you in Git, you will be miserable when using Git.